# How to set the sqlite parameters using C++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I need to set some parameters in `sqlite` like turning the headers on: (.headers ON), setting the output mode to csv : (.mode csv) and I require this to be done with C++ instead of the `sqlite` command line tool.

Can I know whether it is possible or not, and if possible, how to achieve this (using example)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The dot commands are conveniences of the sqlite command line tool. They are not available using the API. CSV is quite easy to build yourself, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Can I please know whether there is any function etc. implemented to get the sqilte output to a csv etc?

Comment: You can try and copy from the [sources of the command line tools](http://www.sqlite.org/src/annotate?checkin=tip&filename=src/shell.c). Search for `output_csv(`